# Numbers that are solutions to polynomials with coefficients that are rational numbers. Do $e$ and $\pi$ belong to this family?

Tags: number-theory, terminology, transcendental-numbers

We know $e$ and $\pi$ are transcendental. Meaning that they aren't the solutions to any polynomial equation with coefficients that are integers. The next obvious question to ask - what about polynomials with coefficients that are rational numbers? Is there a name for such numbers? And has anyone proven that $e$ and $\pi$ don't belong to this family?

The next obvious extension is polynomials with coefficients that are algebraic numbers.

I assume all of these sets will be countable, so it's almost certain $e$ and $\pi$ won't belong to them. Is this a fair assertion to make?

Comment: If a polynomial has rational coefficients then, after multiplication by (for example) the least common multiple of the denominators of those coefficients, the polynomial has integer coefficients.  The multiplication does not affect the roots.  Thus an algebraic number could just as easily be defined as the root of a polynomial with rational coefficients.

Comment: Hmm, okay that solves the first part pretty easily. Now what about polynomials with algebraic coefficients?

Comment: It has been years since I dealt with these ideas (I'm an analyst, and tend to avoid algebra), but I believe that the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is identical to the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is any algebraic number.  That is, you get the algebraic numbers either way.  However, as I don't have a proof top of mind, it is quite possible that I am wrong.

Comment: Dupe of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783334/24), but it's not clear the answers there will be at your level (which you have not revealed, e.g. do you know any field theory?)

Comment: Being the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients is the same as being the root of a polynomial with rational coefficients is the same as being the root of a polynomial with algebraic coefficients. All of those numbers are algebraic numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that one is the same question. @Gone - you're right, the answer there is above my level. But I'll try and tread the path and ask more specific questions.